# Convergence $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, divergent-series

I´m asking for some help, since I am stuck with a proof for convergence like follows:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

I tried to separate it:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\ln\left(n^2+1\right) - \ln\left(n^2\right)\right)=...$$

But I am still stuck, maybe my idea is quite wrong.
I´m looking forward to some help/solutions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Comparison test with $\sum_n 1/n^2$, using the fact that $\ln(1+x) \le x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{1}{n^2}
$$
and $\sum_{n \geq 1}^{ }1/n^2$ converges then it is the same for $\sum_{n \geq 1}^{ }\ln\left(1+1/n^2\right)$.

Or using partial sums :
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k^2} \leq 1+\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{1}{k\left(k-1\right)} = 1+ \sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)
$$
Can you take it from there ?

Comment: Thank you, for your fast reply!! but I am still  bit lost with the partial sums, could you clarify a bit more? Thank you :)

Comment: Actually, $\sum_{k=1}^{N}u_k \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}u_k$. Hence you can consider the partial sum as a sequence that converges or not. Then as $u_n>0$, the partial sum is increasing, if you show that the partial is majored, then you have the convergence of the sequence of the partial sums.